# Getting out in single line using sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is if two tables having same date need to give output in single line, for example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

| Column AA | Column BB |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 5 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 6 |

Output should be as

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2,Cell 5 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4,Cell 6 |

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question title states _sql developer_ yet you tagged your question as [plsqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info). These are two very different things. So is the question title wrong or is the tag wrong?

Comment: Note: It's unclear if you want to use `union` or `union all`, you could answer that by adding further sample data and expected results

Comment: And plsqldeveloper means Oracle is used.

Answer (score 1):

You need `UNION` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT colA, listagg(colB,',') WITHIN GROUP (order by colB) from
(SELECT colA, colB from table1
UNION
SELECT colAA, colBB from table2)
GROUP BY colA;
```

Note: Oracle specific syntax is used.